# non static not inner asyntask with weak-references makes Activity leakable?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

If I have a non static (not inner) Asyntask class, and I run it from an activity that is destroyed without cancelling the Task (all references to the activity from the asyntask are weak-references)... will the Asynctask will have an unintended reference to the activity (because it is not static) making it a memory leak for a while?

I need the AsyncTask to continue running until ending (and can take a while), so cancelling it is not an option.

Comment: what actually you want to do in post execute?

Comment: In the postexecute nothing really...  Saving some results on a local DB (i can do it inBackground).... but i don't really thing it's relevant for the answer...